# Problems with launch python script from rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to launch a python script with no external dependencies from my rails app. I need to add the folder to `PYTHONPATH` and start the script. I tried this:

```
puts system(PYTHONPATH=../lib/python/ python ../reporter/src/reporter.py)
```

but the script does not work. It should create a specific file, but it doesn't. I also tried:

```
puts system("PYTHONPATH=../lib/python/ | python ../reporter/src/reporter.py")
```

but I received the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named...."
```

It looks as though `PYTHONPATH` is not set in the second case. What am I doing wrong? How I can start the python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`system("export PYTHONPATH=../lib/python/ && python ../reporter/src/reporter.py")`

You may also need to put the full path in and use Rails.root.to_s

Comment: "&&" means if the first command runs successfully then run the next command.